# Laravel 8 each time view product, update array and save it to cookies

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-8

I am trying to implements product recently viewed into my application.
I need to add the customers viewed products into cookies, which I will push them latter to my database.

in my `ProductController` `show` function I did this.

```
        $item_array[] = [ $product->id ];
        $item_data    = json_encode( $item_array );
        Cookie::queue( 'recently_viewed', $item_data, 10 );
```

and in my blade I started to check.

```
@if(Cookie::get('recently_viewed'))
    @php
        $recently_views = json_decode(Cookie::get('recently_viewed'), true);
    @endphp
    @foreach($recently_views[0] as $recently_view)
        {{ $recently_view }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

it works but, I just see one id of product into `cookie` which's the one I'm standing on.

How to work around this `$item_array[]` to add the current `id` into this array.

**Update**

I have updated my controller to be something like this.

```
$cookieValue = '';
$cookieValue .= $request->cookie( 'recently_viewed' );
$cookieValue .= (string) $product->id;

Cookie::queue( 'recently_viewed', json_encode( $cookieValue ), 10 );
```

and in view

```
@if(Cookie::get('recently_viewed'))
        @php
            $cookie = Cookie::get('recently_viewed');
            $cookieArray = explode(',', json_decode($cookie));
        @endphp
        {{--{{ dd($cookieArray) }}--}}
        @foreach($cookieArray as $recently_view)
            {!! $recently_view !!}
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

but now I got the results

```
array:1 [▼ 
   0 => ""\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"4\\\\\\\"1\\\"1\"1"1" 
]
```

any way to fix this to be something like.

```
[
    0=>4,
    1=>1,
    2=>5,
]
```

**Update 2**
I have fixed the issue but `json_decode`

```
$cookieValue = "";
$cookieValue .= json_decode( $request->cookie( 'recently_viewed' ) );
$cookieValue .= (string) $product->id . ',';

Cookie::queue( 'recently_viewed', json_encode( $cookieValue ), 10 );
```

the latest update is to ignore the duplicated id.

Comment: You are attaching only one id `$item_array[] = [ $product->id ];` to response. Cookie::queue saves cookies and when you are making response, they are attached to response, but response instance is single for every request, so every time your user make request every time you are attaching only single cookie with productId. I think you should use database to save recent viewed products.

Comment: I am planning to use `database` to save the cookies but, what if customers are not logged in yet.

Comment: You dont need to save cookies in database, when user is on some product page, you should set cookie with product id, if he is on another page with diffrent product id you should get this saved before cookie and add another product id and update this cookie on response.

Comment: @CaShiS see my update please.

Comment: *I am planning to use database to save the *product_id*, *user_id*